# Constant time 'cons'

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

Is there any way (for example, modifying argument types) to make the following 'cons' function take constant time not O(n) time. i.e. building the list should take O(n) time, not O(n^2) time.

Can I do so under the following conditions:

(1) No dynamic memory allocation
(2) x must still remain valid (i.e. may not have references to temporaries)
(3) Type HEAD may have a constructors which are separately compiled (not inlinable)

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename HEAD, typename TAIL>
struct List
{
  List(HEAD head, TAIL tail) : head(head), tail(tail) {}
  typename std::remove_reference<HEAD>::type head;
  typename std::remove_reference<TAIL>::type tail;
};

template <typename HEAD, typename TAIL>
List<HEAD, TAIL> cons(HEAD head, TAIL tail)
{
  return List<HEAD, TAIL>(head, tail);
}

struct Empty {};

int main()
{
  auto x = cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, Empty())));
  // x should still be valid here
}
```

**Example of how can work.**

Compiler knows the type of x, so allocates space on the stack.

So the stack looks like this:

```
| Int1 | Int2 | Int3 |
| p    | p+4  | p+8  |
```

Where `p` is an arbitrary address.

Compiler creates call `cons(2, cons(3, Empty()))`, directing the return value to `p+4`.

Inside `cons(2, cons(3, Empty()))`, compiler creates call to `cons(3, Empty())` directing return value to `p+8`.

This way, each time `cons` is called, `tail` does not need to be copied.

I'm just not sure code so the compiler can (as in, is allowed) to do this optimization. If there is another way of getting constant run time though, I'd be happy to use that.

Comment: I don't understand your "no dynamic memory allocation" requirement. Isn't that what `cons` normally *does*?

Comment: Can you explain in what terms exactly your present `cons` is linear? There's a fixed number of argument that are not inspected in any way. Did you mean the final expression?

Comment: So you're making a linked list. And it contains, not references to things, but copies of them. So I guess the O(n^2) comes from the fact that every nested `cons` call does a copy of its argument, which copies every previously created object into the new one.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be reinventing `std::tuple` with a worse `std::make_tuple` helper. Use that instead. The Standard doesn't make complexity guarantees either for the forwarding constructor of `std::tuple` or for `std::make_tuple` but it's kinda moot because those two uses perfect forwarding, so exactly one move/copy/emplace construction per element is made for a call to `std::make_tuple`; the rest is shuffling references around. It's a linear number of constructions at least.

Of course it's not guaranteed that your compiler will gracefully deal with all the reference shuffling, but you're optimizing at the wrong level anyway.

---

For illustration purposes, almost but not quite what happens:

```
template<typename... T>
class tuple {
    T... members; // this is not correct, only here for illustration

    // The forwarding constructor
    template<typename... U>
    explicit
    tuple(U&&... u)
        : member(std::forward<U>(u)...)
    {}
};

template<typename... T>
tuple<typename std::decay<T>::type...>
make_tuple(T&&... t)
{ return tuple<typename std::decay<T>::type...>(std::forward<T>(t)...); }
```

Thus in a call to `auto tuple = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3)`, there are three temporary `int`s from the call to `make_tuple`, then three `int&&` xvalues from the first calls to `std::forward<int>(t)...` inside `make_tuple` which bind to the arguments of the constructors which are forwarded again as `int&&` xvalues to the conceptual three members of `std::tuple<int, int, int>` which are move constructed from them.

---

Just realized that what I said about the number of constructions only applies the call to `std::make_tuple`, not the whole expression `auto tuple = std::make_tuple(...);`. Since the tuple is returned from the function it may require a move/RVO to the final variable. It's still linear and it's still one of the thing compilers like to optimize and it's still the wrong spot to worry about optimization.

However, C++0x is so filled with goodness that it can already do what you describe in your answer:

```
int i = 3;
std::tuple<int, int, int> tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2, i);
```

The call to `forward_as_tuple` will return a `std::tuple<int&&, int&&, int&>`. This helper never returns a tuple with values, only a 'shallow' tuple of references. The appropriate converting constructor of `std::tuple<int, int, int>` will then initialize its 'members' with two moves and a copy. Note that this silly (un)optimization puts you at risk to write `auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2, i);` which is a tuple with two dangling references.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give an answer to my own question after my investigations, but I'd still be interested if anyone knows a better way.

(1) Rename `List` to `TempList`.
(2) Make the constructors (including move and copy) of `TempList` private.
(3) Make `cons` a friend of `TempList`.
(4) Make `HEAD` and `TAIL` members into references.

Now `TempList` only holds references, so there are no copies. These may be references to temporaries however, but that's ok because temporaries last til the end of the expression, and because `TempList` only has private constructors, it can't be assigned to the LHS of an expression. Only `cons` can create a `TempList`, and can't outlive the expression it is created in.

Now create a function `save` or something of that effect that takes a `TempList` and returns a real `List`, another type that has it's data stored by value.

So we have

`auto x = save(cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, Empty()))));`

And data will be copied or moved at most once (by save), the whole construct now being `O(n)`. The `TempList` structure will probably be optimised away, as long as both `cons` and `save` are inlined.

Comment: That doesn't explain how this is any better than a `std::tuple<int, int, int>(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Sorry, probably not a great example, but lets say instead of `cons` we have `f1`, `f2` and `f3`. Say things like `join`, `remove`, `insert` etc. How would you write functions like that for std::tuple without performing copies at each step?

Comment: You're going to have to perform copies or moves with whatever internal thing you do here anyway, since your `List` contains the actual objects themselves, not references to them. You can't implement `join`, `remove`, `insert` without either copying/moving, or pointers. And if you could, it would already be part of `std::tuple`.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: `TempList` only has references. There's only one copy at the end, when we form a `List`, not the intermediate copies.

Comment: Yes, but once you have a `List`, that's the end. All you're doing is lazy evaluation of expressions. Once you evaluate it, you have a frozen object which can only be copied/moved or referenced.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I didn't say that lazy evaluation was not allowed in my question, just that it's performance needs to be `O(n)`, and not have references to temporary issues.